# Element-ui el-table display not correct, its el-table_body-wrapper's height is smaller

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

When first enter the page that contains the el-table, it displays right. When go to other route page and back, the same el-table > el-table_body-wrapper's height will become smaller.

```
<el-table
  :data="tableData"
  stripe
  highlight-current-row
  :height="tableHeight"
  header-cell-class-name="table-header-class"
  class="main-table">
    <el-table-column
      property="id"
      label="ID"
      align='center'>
    </el-table-column>
    ...
</el-table>
```

When I go to another page and back, I hope the el-table's display not change, but actually the el-table's el-table_body-wrapper html element becomes smaller than before.

Comment: In F12 Developer Tools，
    Begin: .el-table html element's style="height: 689px;", .el-table__body-wrapper html element's style="height: 645px"; 
    After route switch: .el-table html element's style="height: 689px;", .el-table__body-wrapper html element's style="height: 622px"; 
    After route switch, el-table body's height becomes small, producing white space below the table body。

Comment: Can you show how you passed tableHeight prop? Try making this :height fixed value to see if table will change its height.

Comment: The tableHeight prop is vue instance's data variable. Such as: 
    export default {
          data() {
                 return {
                        ...
                        tableHeight: 0,
                        ...
                 }
         } , and will be changed when the browser client area size changing.

Comment: You can try either removing :height="tableHeight" as anyway height property of el-table is set to auto or making it fixed height as  :height="689".

Comment: If I remove :height="tableHeight" , then the header will not show. And the value of height property is reactive by the height of the browser client, so I can's fix its value. I have soluted the problem by modify the source code of element-ui. I changed how to get the headerHeight in table-layout.js. I changed headerHeight from "const headerHeight = this.headerHeight = !this.showHeader ? 0 : headerWrapper.offsetHeight;" to "const headerHeight = !this.showHeader ? 0 : this.headerHeight". Then this will solve my problem 
as long as there is one line in the table header.